# iOS swift You must specify clientID Exception in google integration

Tags: ios, swift

Code:

```
let signIn = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance()
        signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = true
        signIn.clientID = "912597493260-qg351fl8olmnmjl8qobos8n6u909jp0o.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        signIn.scopes = [kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin];
        signIn.trySilentAuthentication();
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
        signIn.delegate = self
```

due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'You must specify |clientID| for |GIDSignIn|

I double checked my code.Even i set client-id getting this exception.Where i went wrong?any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: Have you integrated google configuration file in your Xcode project.

Comment: Have you figured out a fix for this?

Answer (score 15):

I was following Google's own guide for adding Sign-In [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift). I followed it step by step - integrated the google configuration file too. As per the guide, if the configuration file was included, setting the client id manually was not required. Unfortunately, I encountered exactly the same error when I run the app and hit the Sign-In button:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'You must specify |clientID| for |GIDSignIn|'

**Solution:**

For some reason, clientID was not automatically picked from the configuration file. We should instead configure the GIDSignIn object directly, (using the client ID found in the GoogleService-Info.plist file) in the app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
      // Initialize sign-in
      var configureError: NSError?
      GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
      assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
      GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "Cliend id From GoogleService-Info.plist file"
      GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
      return true
}
```

Also, if you are using Firebase, you can do it this way too:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
```

Comment: This didn't work for me but the concept is right on. I still received the same error message so I tried some breakpoint debugging and found GIDSignIn was called in my ViewController.swift before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called. I'm not sure why. Adding the clientID as part of configuring Google Sign-In in ViewDidLoad resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the auto-generated config file, GoogleService-Info.plist, will include the wrong credentials by default; it includes the Web Client credentials instead of the iOS app credentials.

You need to correct the Client ID and the Reverse Client ID in the GoogleService-Info.plist.

Since these credentials are also used in your app's URLSchemes, you need to correct this there too.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue. I followed every step as per the documentation by https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin#swift_9 .

At last, I tried adding Client ID manually on my Controller's viewDidLoad and it worked after a long struggle.

Refer the code below. Replace your project specific Client-ID from GoogleService-info.plist in place of *ClientID* :

---

```
class IntroController: UIViewController {  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()      
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "*ClientID*"
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()       
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The clientId definitely does get picked up from the .plist file.  If it appears not to be, it is likely that your code is attempting to use the sign-in object before it has been properly configured.  Set a breakpoint on your configureWithError line, and make sure that it gets hit before any attempt to set a delegate, perform silent sign-in, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the sign in method has now been updated by google, I was implementing the Google Calendar for iOS app and I found the following code for Sign In:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Initialize sign-in
        var configureError: NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError!)")
    }
```

in their document which gave the same error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'You must specify |clientID| for |GIDSignIn|'
```

I took the lines which were inside:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication)
```

and put them in this method and sign in worked:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```

Code for refernce:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Initialize sign-in
    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError!)")
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to obtain `GoogleService-Info.plist` from https://console.firebase.google.com rather than https://console.developers.google.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Using Firebase remember also that you have to call Firebase.configure() function before you set the clientId. Otherwise, it won't work.