# swift 4 firebase google sign in exception

Tags: xcode, firebase, swift4, gidsignin

I am trying to use firebase google sign in.  I have created a view that I set the class to GIDSignInButton.  I attached an outlet to it in the view controller, but when I run the app and click on the GIDSignInButton, the app crashes with:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'You must specify |clientID| for |GIDSignIn|'

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39885165/1801544 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS swift You must specify clientID Exception in google integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641601/ios-swift-you-must-specify-clientid-exception-in-google-integration)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41018183/google-sign-in-exception-error-swift .

Comment: Write Client ID in applicationdidfinish method of AppDelegate class or in viewDidLoad before the google signin delegating self.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `AppDelegate` class:

```
      GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
      GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
```

If you not use firebase then you can write:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "your client id present in googleservice .plist file"
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
```

It may helps you. Thank you.